# Zephir during compile make errors

Tags: zephir

Environment: OS: Win 10, php 7.4.x.

I have installed Zephir(0.17.0), zephir_parser(1.6.0) - OK.
Command  zephir init  - OK, then i created tsheet.zep file with source code.

But when i am trying compile my zephir class i get error.
My compile command is:
`php zephir.phar compile`

i got following:

```
 Preparing for PHP compilation...
 Preparing configuration file...
 ERROR: mc is required
 Compiling...
```

My question is:  What means: "mc is required" ?   What should i do for resolving this error ?